# C# Script Task To Rename a file based on a wild card search

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to create a C# Script Task to rename a pair of files I receive everyday that has an appended 16 digit time stamp at the end. The files like something like this "Cartons_2018091014000000"

I am pretty low experience when it comes to C# so please forgive my attempt at a logical construction.

Here's what I was thinking would work, but am getting some very non descriptive errors.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        String txtfile = null;
        String[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\test-file-server-name\Scripts\", "Cartons_*");

            foreach (string filename in fileEntries)
        {
            if(filename.Contains("Cartons"))
            {
                txtfile = filename;
                System.IO.File.Move(txtfile, "Cartons.csv");
            }
        }    
        // TODO: Add your code here

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? Or maybe a better / more elegant way to do this in SSIS? I was thinking I would use a ForLoop container, but the reason I don't think it will work is because the file names change every hour due to that timestamp appending.

Comment: What is a "Script Task"?

Comment: `I am pretty low experience when it comes to C#` do you know how to do this in your favorite language? your logic seems completely off.

Comment: @NetMage It's a widget in SSIS. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4217/getting-started-with-the-ssis-script-task/

Comment: You should probably be using `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`, but your test is unneeded - you know every member of `fileEntries` will being with `Cartons` because that is what your wildcard requires. Tell us more about the pair of files - show some samples.

Comment: A script task is basically a partial class container in SSIS that allows you to execute C# driven tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you had it but it was probably saving the file in the runtime path of your exe file. (you just need to add the full path)

```
using System.IO;

class Program
{  
    static public void Main()
    {
        string Path = @"\\test-file-server-name\Scripts\";
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "Cartons_*");

        foreach (string filename in fileEntries)
        {
            if (filename.Contains("Cartons"))
            {
                File.Move(filename, Path + "Cartons.csv");
            }
        }
        // TODO: Add your code here

        //Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much this is what I was looking for. Can't believe I missed the full path, I spun on this for like an hour. Really appreciate the help here.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help. =) I ran into this issue several times before also.  BTW, I think you can remove the "if (filename.Contains("Cartons"))" line also.  Since the Getfiles already requires "Cartons" the statement is not needed. Also to prevent any other files from getting captured you could change the getfiles line to this: "string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "Cartons_*.csv");  or even this string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "Cartons_20??????????????.csv")".  This way other files are not accidentally grabbed... my two cents anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that you are getting a `File already exists` exception when the second file is processed, as you are renaming them all to the same name.

I recommend that you put a breakpoint into your code and re-run the package. This will allow you to step through it to confirm this.

If that is the problem, then you just need to choose new names for the files that are unique.

FWIW, you should be able to achieve the same functionality (move and rename files) using a built-in File System Task rather than scripting it yourself. Here's a tutorial. http://www.rafael-salas.com/2007/03/ssis-file-system-task-move-and-rename.html

Comment: Thank you for responding, I did read this article (truly) and this solution is actually the old method we were using when we got a static set of file names. The change for us is the file names are now moving every hour and we can't set variables and file connections pointed at wild cards. Only the ForEach Container can take a file mask. I really appreciate the feedback though and this is a really great article.